# How can I specify an Extension method in Typescript for an Array<T>?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to add an extension method for an `Array<T>` as below:

```
declare global {  
  interface Array<T> {    
    take<T>(by: number): Array<T>;
  }
}

export namespace Extensions {
  Array.prototype.take = function<T>(this: Array<T>, by: number): Array<T> {
    const self = this;
    return self.filter((x, i) => i < by);
  };
}
```

But when I try to use it, the type returned by the `take` method is `unknown[]`

```
const foo = [{name: "A", age: 1}].take(2);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the value of `this` in your interface as well

```
declare global {  
  interface Array<T> {    
    take<T>(this: Array<T>, by: number): Array<T>;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the type variable from the take method, as it's not being properly used for type inference

```
declare global {  
  interface Array<T> {    
    take(by: number): Array<T>;
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) you can find more information about the typing of `this` parameters in typescript